# Debugging staging docker compose server with pycharm

Tags: docker, docker-compose, wercker

I have the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2'
services:
    postgis:
        image: mdillon/postgis
        environment:
           POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGIS_ENV_POSTGRES_USER}
           POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGIS_ENV_POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
           POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGIS_ENV_POSTGRES_DB}
        volumes:
            - /nexchange/database:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        restart: always
    app:
        image: onitsoft/nexchange:${DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG}
        volumes:
            - /nexchange/mediafiles:/usr/share/nginx/html/media
            - /nexchange/staticfiles:/usr/share/nginx/html/static
        links:
            - postgis
        restart: always
    web:
        image: onitsoft/nginx
        volumes:
            - /nexchange/etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
            - /nexchange/etc/nginx/ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl
            - /nexchange/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
            - /nexchange/mediafiles:/usr/share/nginx/html/media
            - /nexchange/staticfiles:/usr/share/nginx/html/static
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"            
        links:
            - app
        restart: always
```

For some reason, some functionalities that work on the local container do not work on staging.
I would like to configure a `remote interpreter` in pycharm for staging, however it seems like this setup is not currently supported.

I am using `wercker` + `docker compose` and my IDE is pycharm.

EDIT:
The question is:
How to setup Pycharm debugger to run on a remote host running docker compose

Comment: Is this an integration issue between your IDE and the application deployed using docker compose?

Comment: Rather a missing feature in PyCharm that does not allow to use both SSH Tunnel + Docker API

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking?

Comment: I am asking how to debug a remote machine which is running docker in pycharm, as simple as that...

Comment: Is that correct that when run locally you point your debugger to `localhost:443` or `localhost:80` as these are the only ports exported from the setup to the host (explicitly in the above config)? If yes, you should point your debugger to `remotehost:443` or `remotehost:80` and make sure your firewall lets those ports to be accessed. If the above assumption is not correct, then how do you connect the debugger locally?

Comment: You arte wrong... Pycharm users dicker app to debug, and also starts a helper container for that purpose.

Comment: @OlegTikhonov Well then, how is that helper container supposed to know about a docker environment running elsewhere remotely? Forget about docker, have your application run remotely, how would you connect pycham debugger?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution, however not secure, is open the docker API on the remote target to public traffic via `iptables` (possibly to traffic only from specific IP, if you posses a static IP).

```
$ ssh $USER@staging.nexchnage.ru
oleg@nexchange-staging:~# sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2376 -j ACCEPT
oleg@nexchange-staging:~# sudo /etc/init.d/iptables restart
```

And then simply use the docker compose feature of JetBrain PyCharm / PhpStrom or you favourite choice:

[image]

Cheers